# How to don't output false in every itaration

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, strpos

```
<?php
$jobsKeys = array('full.png','hr.png','mobile.png','java.png','python.png','net.png')

?>
<div class="row">
             <ul class="list-group">
             <?php foreach ($item as $job) : ?>
                    <?php
                    foreach($jobIcons as $jobsKeys){
                        if (stripos($job['title'], $jobsKeys['title']) !== false) {
                           echo "<li class='list-group-item'><img src=".$jobsKeys['image']." style='width: 25px;'> ". $job['title'] ." <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>14</span></li>";
                        }else{
                            echo "false";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
         </div>
```

I'am trying to compare the title of the job with the icons from the array (stripos method). And condition when is true works for me the way I want, the problem is with the else statement.

foreach loop returns somthing like this:

```
false
false
false
false
false
<li>....</li>
false
false
false
<li>....</li>
```

I want to get somthinglike this:
if you don't find match in jobIcons(in a whole array) then output false not in not in every itaration. Is it possible to write that in the else statement?

Comment: I wouldn't use an else, since that will trigger each loop. Instead, create a flag, and update it only if a match has been found. After the loop, check to see if the flag is the original value, then output false.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can set a flag whenever you reach the else-statement and check the flag after the for-loop. Something like that:

```
                <?php
                $flag = true;
                foreach($jobIcons as $jobsKeys){
                    if (stripos($job['title'], $jobsKeys['title']) !== false) {
                       echo "<li class='list-group-item'><img src=".$jobsKeys['image']." style='width: 25px;'> ". $job['title'] ." <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>14</span></li>";
                    }else{
                        $flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!$flag) { echo "false"; }
                ?>
```

This is not that elegant because you set the flag every time you encounter the else-statement but it is acceptable for your case I think.